# Shortest representation of a rational function

Tags: numerical-methods, rational-functions

Sometimes a rational function can have multiple representations. As a simple example, we have equality between the following two rational functions, for any $n$

$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^{n-1}
$$

The right hand side is "reduced" in that it is in lowest terms. This really is an $n-1$'th degree polynomial, and if we do polynomial long division on the left hand side, we get the right hand side. However, the left-hand side version is much shorter and easy for computation.

Is there anything that can be said about finding such "short" representations for rational functions, or developing a "canonical" representation that is typically short?

I'm sure that the general problem of finding the ultimate shortest representation is probably too difficult to solve, but I am wondering if there is something simple that can be done at least to make numeric computation easier, in the particular case of rational functions.

Comment: There are two canonical representations of a rational function that come to mind: having it fully factored up top and down below with all common factors cancelled, and having its full partial fraction decomposition. But I'm guessing you want representations with the number of nonzero coefficients minimized. I don't know of a general way to find such a thing. The geometric sum formula (and cyclotomic polynomials in general) is special.

Comment: Are you concerned about the fact that the left-hand side can be defined only for $x\neq 1$ while the right-hand side can be defined for all real $x$?

Comment: David K: if there were a representation that were valid everywhere, that would be better, but certainly the left side is easier to evaluate regardless even if $n$ is modestly large.